# "apt-get build-dep linux" alternative (offline machine)

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, kernel

How to install build dependencies for package linux? There are at least couple of problems I see:

1. Machine to be used is offline one.
2. There is no "*linux*" package according to "*apt-rdepends*" (although "*apt-get build-dep linux*" seems to be working on other machine).
3. Even if "*apt-rdepends -p linux*" was working, number of packages it would list is quit big. isn't there a single offline package for building "*linux*" (which I guess in this meaning stands for kernel)?

Need to use "*apt-get build-dep linux*" comes from Broadcom hybrid_wl wifi drivers readme file, in case soemone is wondering about this.

Comment: You need `linux-generic`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As muru mention it in the comments, not the exact keyword of what you want. If you are just to build a kernel module (like wifi driver). You need the kernel headers (depending on your current kernel type) and basic build tools, plus DKMS.

Some thing: dkms, build-essential, linux-headers-generic | linux-headers-generic-pae | linux-headers-lowlatency | linux-headers-lowlatency-pae

```
sudo install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

However, if your kernel is absolute (headers for that version are not in repository anymore). You need to update kernel and install its headers too.

I recommend: dkms, build-essential, linux-generic | linux-generic-pae | linux-lowlatency | linux-lowlatency-pae

```
sudo install dkms build-essential linux-generic
```

For offline use:

```
sudo download dkms build-essential linux-generic
```

You can also verify and copy build-dep for any other DKMS driver, most have same requirements. See [search for -dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=-dkms&searchon=names).